# Is a particle spin invariant regarding the particle translation through space?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, speed-of-light, quantum-spin

Is a particle spin invariant regarding the particle translation through space? If a person is a collection of particles which speed of translation inside a spaceship very close to the speed of light makes them feel the time passing slower does it mean the particles she is made of are slowed down regarding their internal energy so for example their spin could be possibly affected?

Answer (score 0):

> Is a particle spin invariant regarding the particle translation through space?

Spin at the [quantum level is intrinsic,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_quantum_number) and identifies a particle in the same way that charge and other quantum numbers identify it. Its values are invariant in Lorentz transformations. In composite particles it adds up as part of the angular momentum conservation.

T[his article describes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) how angular momentum is transformed under special relativity.
For angular momentum in general it shows changes:

> Therefore, the components of angular momentum along the direction of motion do not change, while the components perpendicular do change.

For spin it states:

> The spin has a corresponding spin magnetic moment, so if the particle is subject to interactions (like electromagnetic fields or spin-orbit coupling), the direction of the particle's spin vector will change, but its magnitude will be constant.